# VMware tools is not working after update ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualization, vmware

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed as a virtual machine using VMware on a Windows 10 host. After upgrading Ubuntu, VMware tools is no longer working and my system is experiencing problems as a result of that. For example, I can not copy/paste between my OSes, and my screen resolution is limited to 1680x1050.

I've tried reinstalling the [VMware Tools](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018414), but that did not resolve my problem.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: what errors are you getting? Mean while run `sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

Comment: everything works ok, but for example copy and paste from host Os to ubuntu is not woking as before. screen resolution is other problem.

Comment: So the `/sbin/vboxconfig` worked, and now you need your guest additions to work again. if so you need to re-add the guest additions in the guest os.

Comment: my problem is in vmware not in vbox

Comment: Sorry my bad wasn't paying attention...

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing your post to explain exactly what you mean by "not working" and attempting to provide specific information as outlined in http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask in order to help us help you. I don't see enough here to work with.